# Centos 2 interfaces routing

Tags: centos7

I have two remote ESXi server in different datacenter. On both I installed 2 VM pfsense with a site2site VPN with OpenVPN to connect the 2 subnet 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24 over internet.

I have a lot of VM on these two ESXi connected each other via the above subnets.
All can ping each other except one.

This is the situation:

```
Site A: 192.168.10.0/24
Site B: 192.168.20.0/24

Pfsense A: 192.168.10.1/24
Pfsense B: 192.168.20.1/24
VM A1: eth1 192.168.10.2/24 and eth0 1.1.1.1/32
VM A2: 192.168.10.3/24 (single IF with default GTW 192.168.10.1
VM B1: eth0 192.168.20.2/24 and eth1 2.2.2.2/32
```

VM A1 route -n:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         11.11.11.11 0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth0
11.11.11.11 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
1.1.1.1  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.20.0     192.168.10.1    255.255.255.0   UG    100    0        0 eth1
192.168.10.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth1
```

VM B1 route -n:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         22.22.22.22 0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth1
22.22.22.22 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth1
2.2.2.2  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth1
192.168.10.0     192.168.20.1    255.255.255.0   UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.20.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

(11.11.11.11 and 22.22.22.22 is the default gateway given from the provider, I need this configuration to connect from remote on that IP).

The strange thing is:

- I can ping A1 and A2 from B1.
- I can ping B1 from A2.
- I CAN'T ping B1 from A1.

On tcpdump on pfsense, pinging from A1 to B1, I notice that A1 use 1.1.1.1 as IP, instead 192.168.10.2, while B1 and A2 use 192.168.20.2 and 192.168.10.3:

tcpdump on pfsense A, ping pfsense A from A1:

```
19:41:33.739531 IP 192.168.10.2 > 192.168.10.1: ICMP echo request, id 26186, seq 1, length 64
19:41:33.739565 IP 192.168.10.1 > 192.168.10.2: ICMP echo reply, id 26186, seq 1, length 64
```

tcpdump on pfsense A, ping pfsense B from A1:

```
19:41:41.065664 IP 1.1.1.1 > 192.168.20.1: ICMP echo request, id 26193, seq 1, length 64
```

tcpdump on pfsense A, ping B1 from A1:

```
19:41:41.065664 IP 1.1.1.1 > 192.168.20.2: ICMP echo request, id 26193, seq 1, length 64
```

tcpdump on pfsense A, ping B1 from A2:

```
19:42:24.368952 IP 192.168.10.3 > 192.168.20.2: ICMP echo request, id 31618, seq 1, length 64
19:42:24.383237 IP 192.168.20.2 > 192.168.10.3: ICMP echo reply, id 31618, seq 1, length 64
```

tcpdump on pfsense B, ping A1 from B1:

```
19:46:05.538819 IP 192.168.20.2 > 192.168.10.2: ICMP echo request, id 12244, seq 4, length 64
19:46:05.552069 IP 192.168.10.2 > 192.168.20.2: ICMP echo reply, id 12244, seq 4, length 64
```

A1 and B1 are two Centos 7.3 with network manager. The route was added with nmcli.

Why B1 can reach A1 but A1 not? They have the same route!

--EDIT--
I found the problem:
There was a SNAT rule on my A1 iptables. I excluded 192.168.10.2 from translation and now it work.

Comment: Check NAT rules on pfsense A router.

Comment: It's not a firewall problem. A1 exit with IP 1.1.1.1 instead 192.168.10.2 when I try to ping 192.168.20.2

Comment: That is why there's NAT problem.